# Does locking in this situation guarantee that multiple modifications are atomic across threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to determine a solution to a problem I am facing outlined in this [Programmers.SE question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/329458/150520). The specific problem I am facing right now is that I need someway to make multiple atomic modifications to collections from the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace. From what I can tell there is no mechanism in place to do so; concurrent collections only guarantee that single operations are atomic.

One solution to the problem I do not wish to have to implement is to create my own concurrent collection that provides some mechanism or method for multiple atomic operations. I'd like to think I am experienced enough to write my own concurrent collection to allow multiple atomic modifications, though I would much rather use out of the box, well developed classes.

In light of this I have thought of another possible solution using the out of the box collections provided. *My solution is to use a `lock` to control access to parts of code that perform multiple modifications so that they do not interleave each other.*

```
public interface IWork { }
public interface IResource { }

public sealed class WorkPerformer
{
    public static WorkPerformer Instance { get { return lazyInstance.Value; } }
    public static readonly Lazy<WorkPerformer> lazyInstance = new Lazy<WorkPerformer>(() => new WorkPerformer());

    private ConcurrentDictionary<IResource, ConcurrentQueue<Guid>> IResourceWaitQueues { get; set; }
    private ConcurrentDictionary<IWork, ConcurrentDictionary<IResource, Guid>> IWorkToPerform { get; set; }

    private readonly object _LockObj = new object();

    private WorkPerformer()
    {
        IResourceWaitQueues = new ConcurrentDictionary<IResource, ConcurrentQueue<Guid>>();
        IWorkToPerform = new ConcurrentDictionary<IWork, ConcurrentDictionary<IResource, Guid>>();
    }

    private void ModifierTask_MultipleAdds(IWork workToDo)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            lock(_LockObj)
            {
                // -- The point is here I am making multiple additions to IResourceWaitQueues and IWorkToPerform 
                // Find all IResource this IWork uses and generate a Guid for each
                // Enqueue these Guid into their respective ConcurrentQueue's within IResourceWaitQueues
                // Add this IWork and IResource -> Guid mapping into IWorkToPerform
            }
        });
    }

    public void ModifierTask_MultipleRemoves(IWork workThatsDone)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            lock (_LockObj)
            {
                // -- The point is here I am making multiple deletions to IResourceWaitQueues and IWorkToPerform 
                // Find all IResource that this IWork used to perform its work
                // Dequeue from the ConcurrentQueue respective to each IResource used from IResourceWaitQueues
                // Remove this ITask KeyValuePair from IWorkToPerform
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**I was wondering if this solution would work to allow multiple atomic operations to `IResourceWaitQueues` and `IWorkToPerform` in the example code above?**

I would have to assume that it could turn out to be slow sometimes if there are multiple contentions for the `lock`. But other than that if I understand `lock` correctly these the multiple modifications I wish to perform should not interleave each other because only one thread should be allowed in the `lock`ed code at a time.

The only other issue I see is that **I think I would have to `lock` on every other access to `IResourceWaitQueues` and `IWorkToPerform` in the example code above?** Unless of course it is ok for the accesses to be interleaved with the `lock`ed portions of code.

---

**EDIT:** Here is a much more complete code example with some, hopefully, helpful comments on the exact problem I am trying to solve. Again for reference an alternatively worded explanation of the problem and solution is outlined in this [Programmers.SE question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/329458/150520) I asked.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WorkProcessorSandbox
{
    public interface IResource { }

    public interface IWork
    {
        void ProcessWork();
        List<IResource> NeededResources { get; set; }
    }

    // This classes purpose is to process IWork objects by calling their ProcessWork methods when it is found that
    // the IResources they need to process are free. The nature of IResource objects is that they are not threadsafe
    // (though some may be; some must be if an IResource appears in NeededResources multiple times). As a result
    // care must be taken to make sure two IWork do not try to use a distinct IResource simultaneously.

    // This is done by a sort of signalling/ticketing system. Each time a new IWork comes in to be processed it "lines
    // up" for the IResources it needs. Only when it is at the front of the line for all IResource it needs will it
    // move on to process. By forcing atomicity on the "lining up" of the IWork for IResources deadlocks and race conditions
    // can be prevented because the order of an IWork "ticket" in a line can never interleave anothers. 
    public sealed class WorkProcessor
    {
        // Singleton class
        public static WorkProcessor Instance { get { return lazyInstance.Value; } }
        public static readonly Lazy<WorkProcessor> lazyInstance = new Lazy<WorkProcessor>(() => new WorkProcessor());

        // ResourceWaitQueues holds a Queue of Guids mapped to distinct 
        // IResources representing the next IWork that is in line to use it
        private readonly object _Lock_ResourceDict = new object();
        private Dictionary<IResource, Queue<Guid>> ResourceWaitQueues { get; set; }

        // WorkToProcess holds a Dictionary of Guid mapped to IResources representing 
        // the place in line this IWork (that said Dictionary is mapped to) is in for use of the IResources.
        private readonly object _Lock_WorkDict = new object();
        private Dictionary<IWork, Dictionary<IResource, Guid>> WorkToProcess { get; set; }

        private WorkProcessor()
        {
            Running = false;
        }

        private bool Running { get; set; }
        private CancellationToken ProcessingToken { get; set; }
        private CancellationTokenSource ProcessingTokenSource { get; set; }

        // Stops the processing of IWork from the WorkToProcess Dictionary
        public void StopProcessing()
        {
            if (Running)
            {
                ProcessingTokenSource.Cancel();
                Running = false;
            }
        }

        // Starts (Allows) the processing of IWork from the WorkToProcess Dictionary
        public void StartProcessing()
        {
            if (!Running)
            {
                // Instantiate to Empty
                ResourceWaitQueues = new Dictionary<IResource, Queue<Guid>>();
                WorkToProcess = new Dictionary<IWork, Dictionary<IResource, Guid>>();

                // Create CancellationToken for use in controlling Tasks
                ProcessingTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                ProcessingToken = ProcessingTokenSource.Token;
                Running = true;
            }
        }

        // The purpose of this method is to compare the list of Guids at the front of the Queues in ResourceWaitQueues
        // to the list of Guids that each IWork is waiting on for it to start processing. 
        // If the Guids that an IWork needs to start processing is present in the list of Guids at the front of the Queues
        // then the IWork can start processing, otherwise it cannot.
        private void TryProcessWork()
        {
            if(Running)
            {
                // A Task that will go through all of the IWork waiting to be 
                // processed and start processing the IWork objects that are ready.
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    // Here we need to lock on both the ResourceWaitQueues and WorkToProcess locks
                    lock (_Lock_ResourceDict) {
                    lock (_Lock_WorkDict)
                    {
                        // Go through the Dictionary of IWork waiting to be processed
                        foreach (var waitingWork in WorkToProcess)
                        {
                            // Find the List<Guid> that are needed for this IWork to be processed
                            var worksGuids = waitingWork.Value.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();

                            // Find the List<Guid> that are currently ready to be processed 
                            var guidsReadyToProcess = ResourceWaitQueues.Values.Select(x =>
                            {
                                // If a Queue<T> is Empty when it is Peek'd it throws and Exception!
                                if (x.Count > 0)
                                    return x.Peek();
                                return Guid.Empty;
                            }).ToList();

                            // If the List<Guid> needed by this IWork is contained within the List<Guid> ready to be processed
                            if (worksGuids.All(x => guidsReadyToProcess.Contains(x)))
                            {
                                // This IWork is ready to be processed!
                                ProcessWork(waitingWork);

                                // Remove this IWork from WorkToProcess
                                if (!WorkToProcess.Remove(waitingWork.Key))
                                {
                                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Fatal error! Stopping work processing. Could not remove IWork from Dictionary that should contain it.");
                                    StopProcessing();
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }, ProcessingToken);
            }
        }

        // The purpose of this function is to "enqueue" IWork for processing. First a list of all the IResources
        // that the IWork needs to process is created along with a Guid for each unique IResource it uses. 
        // These Guids are then enqueued into the respective Queue in ResourceWaitQueues representing this IWork's
        // "spot in line" to use those specific IResources. Finally the IWork and its Guids are then added to the
        // WorkToPerform Dictionary so that TryProcessWork can determine if it is ready to run or not.
        // TryProcess is called at the end to see if this IWork is possibly ready to process right away.
        public void EnqueueWork(IWork workToDo)
        {
            if (Running)
            {
                // Get all distinct IResource in the IWork's NeededResources
                var worksResources = workToDo.NeededResources.Distinct().ToList();

                // Create the Guids this IWork object will wait on to start processing
                Dictionary<IResource, Guid> worksGuidResourceMap = new Dictionary<IResource, Guid>();
                worksResources.ForEach(x => worksGuidResourceMap.Add(x, Guid.NewGuid()));

                // Here we need to lock on both the ResourceWaitQueues and WorkToProcess locks
                lock (_Lock_ResourceDict) {
                lock (_Lock_WorkDict)
                {
                    // Find all of the IResources that are not currently present in the ResourceWaitQueues Dictionary
                    var toAddResources = worksResources.Where(x => !ResourceWaitQueues.Keys.Contains(x)).ToList();

                    // Create a new entry in ResourceWaitQueues for these IResources
                    toAddResources.ForEach(x => ResourceWaitQueues.Add(x, new Queue<Guid>()));

                    // Add each Guid for this works IResources into the Queues in ResourceWaitQueues
                    foreach (var aGuidResourceMap in worksGuidResourceMap)
                    {
                        foreach (var resourceQueue in ResourceWaitQueues)
                        {
                            if (aGuidResourceMap.Key == resourceQueue.Key)
                                resourceQueue.Value.Enqueue(aGuidResourceMap.Value);
                        }
                    }

                    // Add this IWork and its processing info to the Dictionary of awaiting IWork to be processed
                    WorkToProcess.Add(workToDo, worksGuidResourceMap);
                }
                }

                // Go through the list of IWork waiting to be processed and start processing IWork that is ready
                TryProcessWork();
            }
        }

        // The purpose of this function is to create a Task in which the IWork passed to it can be processed.
        // Once the processing is complete the Task then dequeues a single Guid from the Queue respective to 
        // each IResource it needed to process. It then calls TryProcessWork because it is most likely possible
        // there is some IWork that is now ready to process.
        private void ProcessWork(KeyValuePair<IWork, Dictionary<IResource, Guid>> workToProcess)
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                // Actually perform the work to be processed.
                workToProcess.Key.ProcessWork();

                // Get the list of the IResources that were used during processing
                var usedResources = workToProcess.Value.Select(x => x.Key).ToList();

                // We are removing multiple Guids from the ResourceWaitQueues. They must be atomic. 
                // The ResourceWaitQueues could become incoherent if any other operations are performed on it during the dequeueing.
                // It is ok for WorkToProcess to be modified while this is happening.
                lock (_Lock_ResourceDict)
                {
                    // Get the Queues corresponding to these IResources
                    var resourceQueues = ResourceWaitQueues.Where(x => usedResources.Contains(x.Key)).Select(x => x.Value).ToList();

                    try
                    {
                        // Dequeue a Guid from each of these Queues exposing the next Guid to be processed on each
                        resourceQueues.ForEach(x => x.Dequeue());
                    }
                    catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
                    {
                        Console.Out.WriteLine("Fatal error! Stopping work processing. Could not dequeue a Guid that should exist: " + ex.Message);
                        StopProcessing();
                    }
                }

                // Go through the list of IWork waiting to be processed and start processing IWork that is ready
                TryProcessWork();

            }, ProcessingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using ConcurrentQueue and ConcurrentDictionary should remove the need for any explicit locking, however you need to understand how to utilise those collections effectively or they can end up causing race conditions. I would suggest reading about them more and the techniques that can be used on each and then review your code again.

Comment: @mbrdev Yes they do remove the need for explicit locking, but only when you perform *single atomic operations on them*. They provide no mechanism for *multiple atomic operations* to be performed. Thus I think locking is required in my problem. I am also aware of ways to prevent race conditions and deadlock in multithreaded code (the reason I ask this question is to prevent such conditions).

Comment: There's no reason to use `ConcurrentDictionary` if you're going to synchronize access to it, just use a `Dictionary`.

Comment: My point really is that if you will wrap operations to those collections with a lock then there doesn't seem to be a point to using the concurrent namespace at all as the explicit lock will remove the benefits. Could you explain why you need to add / remove multiple items as part of a single "atomic" operation? If I understand what you are trying to do then maybe I can suggest an alternative, otherwise I believe using the lock like that is probably the way forward, however, i woild consider using a double lock.

Comment: @Servy That makes a lot of sense. I need to put some thought into it before I say for sure, but assuming all other single modifications to the `Dictionary`s cannot interleave the multiple modifications then the locking in `ConcurrentDictionary` is useless because as you point out I would already synchronizing access.

Comment: @KDecker That assumption does not in fact hold.  You're going to need to lock around *all* usages of these dictionaries in order to have these operations be logically atomic.

Comment: @Servy Indeed, I don't think I worded the last comment correctly to convey that point.

Comment: Is it possible to just use multiple instances of IResource objects, I.e. Have your IWork object instantiate its own dependencies? Depending on the number of IWork instances and the probability of them requiring a similar set of IResource objects it could end up with pretty much running in a single threaded way if all of your threads are nearly always waiting for resources. An IOC framework might help here or you could wrote some custom code to instantiate the IResource objects as needed.

Comment: @mbrdev This is an interesting thought that I had not considered, though I do not think it is possible for the types of `IResource` I create. The majority of my resources are singleton `SerialPort` communication classes. Though they are written to be thread safe, in the future I anticipate non-thread safe resources to appear; some exist now that write to files. // At this point I could technically skimp out and require all resources to be thread safe but its not very future proof I feel. Also this method ensures the ordering of `IWork` which is important in a lot of circumstances I face.

Comment: Ok I understand the real problem now, I'll work on a proper answer below as comments aren't long enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that accurately illustrates your scenario, it's impossible to say for sure. But based on your description so far, it seems reasonably clear that using `lock` will address your primary issue (atomicity of some grouped series of operations)

Whether you need to also use `lock` on all other accesses of the same objects depends on what those accesses are and how they relate to the grouped operations you're protecting with `lock`. For sure, there is no need to use `lock` just to make sure that the collections remain coherent. Their internal synchronization will ensure that.

But if your grouped operations represent some type of coherency in and of itself, where other accesses to the objects would be incorrect if they were allowed to take place while a grouped operation was in progress then, yes, you would need to also use `lock`, with the same `_LockObj` reference, to ensure that the grouped operation could not take place at the same time any other access was taking place which depended on the coherency of the data structure in aggregate.

If you need more specific advice than that, please improve the question so that it's clear how all of these operations actually relate.

*Aside*: you may want to consider following normal .NET coding conventions: restricting your use of Pascal casing to methods and properties, and using camel-casing for fields. This will make it easier for readers to follow your code.

I would say that for sure, it's a very bad choice to use for fields the .NET convention for interface naming (i.e. Pascal-cased identifiers which always start with `I`). You are sure to make it very difficult for people to understand your code when you do that.

Comment: Thank you Peter, this makes sense. I will work on a complete SSCCE just to make sure I am clear on the issues I am facing. I will also be taking into account Servy's comment on the question itself that I could be using `Dictionary` instead of `ConcurrentDictionary` because I will be synchronizing access myself (Again assuming my other single accesses to the `Dictionary`s cannot interleave the multiple accesses). // Also I will look into your aside, I have the issue of being the only programmer on all projects I have ever worked on, so I rarely get to confer with other professionals.

Comment: I have added a more complete code example to the question if you would like to take a look and maybe comment.

Comment: @KDecker: please see [mcve] for advice on what a good MCVE look like. The code you added does help comprehend the scenario, but it's still not entirely clear. One thing I don't see is a mechanism where if one task requires resource A and another task requires resource B, both tasks get to run concurrently. Maybe in a full MCVE we would be able to see concurrent calls to `TryProcessWork()`; they're not visible here though.

Comment: @KDecker: At this point, it does seem like your follow-up question is more appropriate for Programmers than here; i.e. you don't seem to have an actionable problem statement or known bug you're trying to fix. I do think the code could probably be improved, but lacking an MCVE I wouldn't want to spend very much time trying to say how.

Answer (score 2):

To maximise performance you should avoid locking X number of `IResource` objects for the duration of the `IWork.ProcessWork` method. The problem is if you have an `IWork` object that requires 10 `IResource` objects, 9 of those resources may take only a few milliseconds to process while the 10th could take minutes, in this scenario, all 10 of the resource objects will be locked so that no other `IWork` object can use them for the full time it takes to complete the work.

By creating a `LockResource` method and a `ReleaseResource` method, you can use the `ConcurrentDictionary` as it's designed without the need of wrapping it in a `lock` as you will only be performing atomic operations, i.e. add `IResource` to `ResourceWaitQueue` and remove `IResource` from `ResourceWaitQueue`. This will allow your `IWork` objects to execute in an efficient way where the only bottle neck is the actual resources rather than the code.